# Multi-screen flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

someone know how to do layout in flexbox like this? (img layout) I spent quite a lot time to try finish this.

[image: img layout]

```
<div class="sampleRow">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/333x185"/>
    <ul>
      <li>Sample text</li>
      <li>asdadasd</li>
      <li>asdasdasd</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>asdasdasd</li>
      <li>asdasdas</li>
      <li>saqweasdd</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>asdsadqwe</li>
      <li>adqweqwe</li>
      <li>cxvxcvxfsd</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum.</p>  
</div>
```

[demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/howilion/6hdg8xa5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add media queries and in media queries set flex direction and more styles.

Or you can use bootstrap 4 and responsive flex classes.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

I have added two divs, as a layout helpers.

But this is not ideal solution, a bit dirty I would say.

On desktop paragraph is positioned in a bit hacky way. But it's the best I can do with flexbox here I suppose.

---

Note that this layout would be done better and easier with css grid. It is 2 dimensional layout system, so fits perfectly here.

You can read about it:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout
    https://jsfiddle.net/4L7tk9v1/8/

---

**Solution**:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/4L7tk9v1/8/
```

```
<div class="sampleRow">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/333x185"/>
    <ul>
      <li>Sample text</li>
      <li>asdadasd</li>
      <li>asdasdasd</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="helper">
      <ul>
        <li>asdasdasd</li>
        <li>asdasdas</li>
        <li>saqweasdd</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <ul>
        <li>asdsadqwe</li>
        <li>adqweqwe</li>
        <li>cxvxcvxfsd</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum.</p>  
</div>
```

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.sampleRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;

  > img {
    object-fit: contain;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }

  ul {
    flex-basis: 50%;

    li {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }
  }

  .empty {
   flex-basis: 50%;
  }

  .helper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }

  p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 578px) {
  div.sampleRow {
    .empty {
      flex-basis: 0;
    }
    > ul {
      flex-basis: calc(50% / 3);
    }
    .helper {
      flex-basis: calc((50% / 3 ) * 2);
    }
    .helper ul {
      flex-basis: 50%;
    }
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  div.sampleRow {
    p {
      max-width: 50%;
      flex-basis: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```